# Problems with checksum modulo 256 C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, range, checksum, modulo

I am a student industrial engineering in the field of electrotechnics. I am not used to work with c#. I am trying to make a checksum tha consists of 2 bytes.
The checksum is computed with the following algorithm:

```
A = 0xFF 
B = 0 

For I FROM 0 TO number_of_bytes -1 DO 
   A := (A + DATA[I]) mod 0x100; 
   B := (B + A) mod 0x100; 
END 

checksum[0] := A 
checksum[1] := B
```

A and B are byte values and the addition is made `modulo 256`.

When i run the program it breaks at `A += byteToCalculate[i];`
This warning occures:

> "An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in communicatie.exe but was not handled in user code."

Can someone help me with this problem?

```
    public void ChecksumBerekenen(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        byte[] byteToCalculate = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x58, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00, bytewaarde_2[3], bytewaarde_2[2], bytewaarde_2[1], bytewaarde_2[0] };

        int A = 0xff;
        int B = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= byteToCalculate.Length ; i++)
        {
            A += byteToCalculate[i];
            A %= 0x100;

            B += A ;
            B %= 0x100;
        }
        VerstuurdeData.AppendText(A.ToString("x") + " " + B.ToString("x"));
    }
```

Comment: Change `<=` to `<`. Starting at zero, you want to look up to length - 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid such *pesky errors* (`<=` instead of required `<`) use *foreach* loop:

```
  foreach (var item in byteToCalculate) {
    A += item;
    A %= 0x100;

    B += A;
    B %= 0x100;
  }
```

and you'll have a more *readable* code as a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here: `for (int i = 0; i <= byteToCalculate.Length ; i++)`

You want this `for (int i = 0; i < byteToCalculate.Length ; i++)`

Array indices are 0-based so you want to iterate to 1 less than the length.